# Android getString() returns wrong string

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm facing the Problem that getString() returns not the String of the id but another string. But first here is my Code:

```
public public class ShopFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    public class ShopManager(){
        ...
        private TableRow[] getRowsFromItems(){
        ...
        TextView headlineName = new TextView(getContext());
        headlineName.setText(getString(R.string.shop_headline_name));
        TextView headlinePrice = new TextView(getContext());
        headlinePrice.setText(getString(R.string.shop_headline_price));
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    ...
    <string name="show_leaderboards">Leaderboards</string>
    <string name="show_achievements">Achievements</string>
    ...
    <string name="shop_headline_name">Article</string>
    <string name="shop_headline_price">Price</string>
    ...
</resources>
```

The Problem is, that getString(R.string.shop_headline_name) returns "Achievements" and getString(R.string.shop_headline_price) returns "Leaderboards". I have no idea how to fix this and I'm quite confused why this happens. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your answers

Comment: Clean the project (e.g., Build > Clean Project in Android Studio) and see if that helps.

Comment: If you've the **instant run** enabled, it could be causing it. It's still a broken thingy, don't use it!

Answer (score 11):

Clean and build should do the trick. Your R.java, which holds all the ids, was not generated properly. A clean and build will generate it properly.

Answer (score 1):

To use your string from Resource folder (here `strings.xml`), use this code :

```
headlineName.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.shop_headline_name));
```

This should work.

Comment: getString(int resId) internally implements getResources().getString(resId). Hence, no need for getResource()